# YSOD when passing complex type as razor model in NancyFX

Tags: razor, nancy

I'm getting a YSOD when sending a model of type `IEnumerable<string>` to my Razor view in NancyFX. Everything works well if supply a string as the model, with the relevant `@model` statement in the view, so *its* working.

The error is

> Unable to discover CLR Type for model by the name of System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.  Ensure that the model passed to the view is assignable to the model declared in the view.

What have I missed?

View.cshtml

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.String>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <h3>@item</h3>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

The Module

```
public class MyModule: NancyModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters => View["View", this.GetModel()];
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetModel()
    {
        return new[] { "one", "two" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `@model` directive isn't supported in Nancy. Swapping the `@model` for an `@inherits` with the correct type fixes the issue:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<My.ViewModels.WhateverViewModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to [Greg B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12935564/26463), `@model` is nonetheless a reserved term in the RazorEngine for Nancy, even though this isn't clear from the [Nancy Razor View Engine](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine) page.

So, you can't declare a variable with the name `model` and reference it with `@model.Property` for instance; the view engine will still try to bind it to the model, even if that doesn't actually work ([Razor View Engine line 354](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor/RazorViewEngine.cs#L354)) and you'll get the same error.