# NancyFX error when trying to use model in view

Tags: c#, razor

so I was making an application using NancyFX SelfHost and it runs perfectly, index etc shows, but when I go to the loginpage I get a "Razor Compilation Error" without any errors. I tried the solutions to the following questions: [Razor Compilation Error using NancyFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199555/razor-compilation-error-using-nancyfx) and [YSOD when passing complex type as razor model in NancyFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863474/ysod-when-passing-complex-type-as-razor-model-in-nancyfx) tried googling and trying every possible solution but it didnt work. This is my login.cshtml:

```
@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<Test.Models.AuthModel>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        Username <input type="text" name="Username" />
        <br />
        Password <input name="Password" type="password" />
        <br />
        Remember Me <input name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="True" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
    @if(@Model.Errored)
    {
        <div>Invalid Username or Password</div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Visual studio says this gives a couple errors:

```
The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context  

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 

The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

'_Page_Views_login_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override
The name 'Context' does not exist in the current context

The type or namespace name 'Nancy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

all these error are in login.cshtml...

Then the AuthModule.cs:

```
public class AuthModule : NancyModule
    {
        public AuthModule()
        {
            Get("/login", args =>
            {
                AuthModel model = new AuthModel();
                model.Errored = this.Request.Query.error.HasValue;
                return Negotiate.WithView("login").WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK).WithModel(model);
            });
            Post("/login", args => {
                var userGuid = UserDatabase.ValidateUser((string)this.Request.Form.Username, (string)this.Request.Form.Password);

                if (userGuid == null)
                {
                    return this.Context.GetRedirect("~/login?error=true&username=" + (string)this.Request.Form.Username);
                }

                DateTime? expiry = null;
                if (this.Request.Form.RememberMe.HasValue)
                {
                    expiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
                }

                return this.LoginAndRedirect(userGuid.Value, expiry);
            });
        }
    }
```

BootStrapper.cs:

```
public class BootStrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
        {
            base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);

            nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(
                StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/assets")
            );
        }

        protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
        {
            base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);


            container.Register<IRazorConfiguration, RazorConfig>().AsSingleton();
            container.Register<IUserMapper, UserDatabase>();
            container.Register<RazorViewEngine>();
        }

        protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
        {
            base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);
            pipelines.OnError += (ctx, ex) =>
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
                return null;
            };
            var formsAuthConfiguration = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
            {
                RedirectUrl = "~/login",
                UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>(),
            };
            FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formsAuthConfiguration);
        }
    }
```

RazorConfig:

```
public class RazorConfig : IRazorConfiguration
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetAssemblyNames()
        {

        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetDefaultNamespaces()
        {

        }

        public bool AutoIncludeModelNamespace
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
```

I am out of ideas on how to fix this, if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Hairydruidy it got solved going to beta Nancy 2.0

Comment: Thanks for the info. The versioning is kind of weird. The oldest version I can find of 2.0 is from 2016 while 1.4.4 was released in 2017. I will update the version and try it out. Thanks again